# SQL insert value into column on a specific match

Tags: sql, sql-server, parsing

I have a table consisting of roughly 4000 rows. I am parsing through the column `Text` in the table and finding every instance of the word 'Fern' and from that the value in the third position of the string I am placing into another column named `PONumber`. My third column `RowKey` is an identity column and tells me what rows the word I am searching for is on.

For example the first instance of the word Fern is on row 1 while the next instance is on row 24. I am trying to get the value from the first instance into the `PONumber` column from row 1-23. The next instance is on row 24 and ends on row 28, so I would need that value in the `PONumber` column on rows 24-28 and so on....

I am having trouble selecting only that range and placing the value into the corresponding rows in the `PONumber` column

My code so far:

```
DECLARE @i INT, @maxCount INT;

select @maxCount = max(RowKey) from Flowers

WHILE @i <= @maxCount
SET @i = 1;
BEGIN
    SELECT Text, PONumber, RowKey FROM Flowers
    WHERE CHARINDEX('Fern', Text) > 0
    
    'I need to grab that value and INSERT INTO Number column

END
```

Sample Data:

```
  Text                                      PONumber
1 Fern Flower 12345678  More text           12345678
.                                           12345678
.                                           12345678
.                                           12345678
.                                           12345678
.                                           12345678
.
23
24 Fern Flower 23456789 More text           PONumber
.                                           23456789
.                                           23456789
.                                           23456789
.                                           23456789
29
```

Comment: What do you mean by "line"? Do you mean you have a string value in a row that has line breaks in it, or do you actually mean a row? The fact you use the word "row" later implies the former; but that makes the statement *"I have a table consisting of roughly 4000 lines"* even more confusing? Does that mean it have 400 rows, of which every row has 9 line breaks in it ( (making 10 lines of text in each row for a total of 4000 "lines"?). Sample data and expected results will help us help you.

Comment: @Larnu sorry I mean row, I will add in sample data in one second, I fixed it to say 'rows'

Comment: @Larnu I added in some sample data to hopefully better clarify what I am trying to do

Comment: Seems like, you are just after the last "word" in a string now.

Comment: Sample data fixed to show

Comment: Want to move the goal posts any more before I edit my answer for a 3rd time..?

Comment: @Larnu No it is accurate now, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These types of situations are tricky and can be a real bear to wrestle with.

My first note is to consider adding a PONumber column to your data and capturing that upon insert vs parsing text. Having said that, here's an idea to address your current need.

First, here's a function designed to parse your "fern" po number from a text value:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetPO (
    @text varchar(8000)
)
RETURNS varchar(255)
WITH RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE 
        @pos int = CHARINDEX ( 'fern', @text ),
        @po varchar(255);

    IF @pos > 0 BEGIN

        -- Locate the starting position of the first numeric value.
        -- Ass-u-mes *any* numeric value following the word "fern" is the expected po.

        WHILE ISNUMERIC ( SUBSTRING ( @text, @pos, 1 ) ) = 0 AND @pos <= LEN ( @text )
            SET @pos = @pos + 1;

        -- If @pos is not equal to @text's length then assume a @po value was found. 
        
        IF @pos < LEN ( @text ) BEGIN

            WHILE ISNUMERIC ( SUBSTRING ( @text, @pos, 1 ) ) = 1 BEGIN
                
                SET @po = ISNULL ( @po, '' ) + SUBSTRING ( @text, @pos, 1 );
                SET @pos = @pos + 1;

            END

        END

    END

    RETURN @po;

END
GO
```

Running `SELECT dbo.GetPO ( 'Fern Flower 12345678  More text' );` returns `12345678`.

Next, to continue your previous PONumber in the event `GetPO` returned `NULL`, here is an example how you might go about that using `dbo.GetPO`:

```
DECLARE @Data table ( [Text] varchar(8000), RowKey int IDENTITY (1,1) );
INSERT INTO @Data VALUES
    ( 'Fern Flower 12345678  More text' ),
    ( '.' ),
    ( '.' ),
    ( 'Fern Flower 23456789 More text' ),
    ( '.' );

;WITH cte AS (
    
    SELECT
        RowKey,
        [Text],
        dbo.GetPO ( [Text] ) AS PONumber
    FROM @Data

)
SELECT
    RowKey,
    [Text],
    CASE
        WHEN PONumber IS NULL THEN (
            -- Get the most recent non-null PONumber.
            SELECT TOP 1 PONumber FROM cte AS x WHERE x.RowKey < cte.RowKey AND x.PONumber IS NOT NULL ORDER BY x.RowKey DESC
        )
        ELSE PONumber -- Keep the existing PONumber.
    END AS PONumber
FROM cte
ORDER BY RowKey;
```

**Returns**

```
+--------+---------------------------------+----------+
| RowKey |              Text               | PONumber |
+--------+---------------------------------+----------+
|      1 | Fern Flower 12345678  More text | 12345678 |
|      2 | .                               | 12345678 |
|      3 | .                               | 12345678 |
|      4 | Fern Flower 23456789 More text  | 23456789 |
|      5 | .                               | 23456789 |
+--------+---------------------------------+----------+
```

**UPDATE**

Here's an example of continuing your PONumber across NULL values using a combination of my and @Larnu's examples:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    
    SELECT
        RowKey,
        [Text],
        LEFT( STUFF( YT.[Text], 1, CI1.I-1, '' ), CI2.I - CI1.I ) AS PONumber
    FROM @Data YT
    CROSS APPLY (
        VALUES ( NULLIF ( CHARINDEX ( 'Fern Flower', YT.[Text] ), 0 ) + LEN ( 'Fern Flower' ) + 1 )
    ) CI1 ( I )
    CROSS APPLY (
        VALUES ( ISNULL ( NULLIF ( CHARINDEX ( ' ', YT.[Text], CI1.I ), 0 ), LEN ( YT.[Text] ) ) )
    ) CI2 ( I )

)
SELECT
    RowKey,
    [Text],
    CASE
        WHEN PONumber IS NULL THEN (
            -- Get the most recent non-null PONumber.
            SELECT TOP 1 PONumber FROM cte AS x WHERE x.RowKey < cte.RowKey AND x.PONumber IS NOT NULL ORDER BY x.RowKey DESC
        )
        ELSE PONumber -- Keep the existing PONumber.
    END AS PONumber
FROM cte
ORDER BY RowKey;
```

**Returns**

```
+--------+---------------------------------+----------+
| RowKey |              Text               | PONumber |
+--------+---------------------------------+----------+
|      1 | Fern Flower 12345678  More text | 12345678 |
|      2 | .                               | 12345678 |
|      3 | .                               | 12345678 |
|      4 | Fern Flower 23456789 More text  | 23456789 |
|      5 | .                               | 23456789 |
+--------+---------------------------------+----------+
```

Comment: A `WHILE` could be incredibly slow here, and combine that with a multi-line function, which are known to perform slowly too, and you could get something really slow. Note as well that `ISNUMERIC` is not a great function. It returns both false positives and false negatives. `TRY_CONVERT` is a far better function.

Comment: I'm not a fan of WHILE either, and good note on TRY_CONVERT @Larnu. I'll give it a go when I have a minute.

Comment: I've updated this example with a combination of my PONumber "carrying" and @Larnu's PONumber parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that all the values are prefixed with `'text'` then is seems you could just use `CHARINDEX` and `STUFF` to remove that section of text:

```sql
SELECT STUFF(YourColumn,1,NULLIF(CHARINDEX('text',YourColumn),0)+5,'') AS PONumber
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

---

Edit: Based on the latest version, then it's not `'text'` it's `'Fern Flower'` and then you just need the left most characters to the next space (or end of the value?):

```sql
SELECT YT.YourColumn,
       LEFT(STUFF(YT.YourColumn,1,CI1.I-1,''),CI2.I - CI1.I) AS PONumber
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('Fern Flower',YT.YourColumn),0)+LEN('Fern Flower') + 1))CI1(I)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' ',YT.YourColumn,CI1.I),0),LEN(YT.YourColumn))))CI2(I);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d4c2643afacf2dfa6d7a0938321c41ba)

Comment: I made it confusing again my bad 'Text' is my column name and the text to the right of Fern is just more text contained on the row. The value to the right of text is an 8-digit number that is what I'm placing into the PONumber column

Comment: if the sample data isn't representative, that won't help, @TheCodeLab . This is based on  the data you have supplied.

Comment: Updated @TheCodeLab , but I won't be addressing any more goal post movements.

Comment: This appears to skip the first digit of the "PONumber".

Comment: Fixed, @CriticalError .